# C++ How to make function perform faster?

Tags: c++, function

I have this function, and they are don't work fast enough. Do you have any idea how to write it in more efficient way?

```
void IntervalSet::add(const SimpleInterval & interval)
{
    if (interval.isEmpty())
        return;

    m_intervals.push_back(interval);
    tidy();

    assert(isConsistent());
}

void IntervalSet::add(const IntervalSet & intervalSet)
{
    for(auto &interval : intervalSet.m_intervals)
        add(interval);
    assert(isConsistent());
}
```

Comment: What is `m_intervals`?

Comment: What does `tidy()` and `isConsistent()` do?

Comment: When you say don't work fast enough, in relation to what? Speed you expect? Another implementation that does the same thing faster? Need a point of reference.

Comment: m_intervals is linked list of SimpleIntervals

Comment: Yea exactly, another implementation that does the same thing faster.

Comment: @filcitheking Is this other implementation written in c++? Do you have source for it?

Comment: Where's the definition of `SimpleInterval` and `IntervalSet`?  Please include them in your post.

Comment: Bad coding style.  Identifier names should differ in more than case.  For example `IntervalSet` and `intervalSet` should differ in more than the lower case `i`.

Comment: Performance:  Remove the first `add` function.  There are really not enough statements to warrant a separate function.  By place the content into the 2nd `add` function, you eliminate branch instructions.  Branch instructions may cause the processor to slow down (either by reloading the instruction pipeline or performing branch prediction calculations).

Comment: Performance:  Remove the `tidy()` function call per each smaller add.  Use the `tidy` after all elements are added to the set.  Same thing with the `assert` call.

Comment: Performance:  Reserve space in a vector if you know the number of elements to push back.  This will reduce the number of possible re-allocations in memory (as the vector grows, it may need to expand which cause reallocation of memory and copying of the elements; very time consuming).

Comment: Profile.  Did you set the optimization settings for high-speed?  Profile.  Did you look at the assembly language, is the compiler using optimal instructions?  Profile.  Are the posted function the source of the time?  Do all operations need to be in the loop? (For example, using repetitive addition versus multiplication.)

Answer (score 0):

push_back() may be heavy depending on the container. If you are using it in a vector, maybe try reserving in advance the size if you know it, or instead reserve larger blocks to mitigate allocation overhead.

UPDATE:

To be honest, its all too vague a question. tidy() & isConsistent() are black boxes and its unknown what they do, how they do it, and if they can do it better. So commenting on the efficiency of the code in the function could be a red herring.

Usage of the list as a container might not be the best unless quick insertion and removal mid way through the container is required. Vector might be a better option, and should be used in a way to reduce allocation to a minimum (reallocation would require a copy of the entire contents of the container, so the larger it gets the slower it is to push_back(), prefer reserve() if possible).

Also, no information is given about the context of the usage of this function. i.e it might not be inefficiencies in the function, rather how it is called and how often it is called might be the bottleneck.